# NDMP with NBU 7 issue

Tags: netbackup

I am having issues with NDMP and NBU 7.0

I get the following error:
Error bpbrm(pid=2540) db_FLISTsend failed: file read failed (13)
Error ndmpagent(pid=2660) terminated by parent process
Error ndmpagent(pid=2660) NDMP backup failed, path

It appears that the NBU may not be reading information from the NDMP client properly.
Any thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I've only met these terms in reference to Symantec BackupExec, I think, so my first guess is - is there a remote server, and a firewall involved, which might be blocking some ports?

My second guess is - can it read the file? Does it exist, does it have read permissions, are there other programs involved holding files open?

What systems/OS's/versions are you using? Can you get more detailed logs to find which file is failing to be read?

Comment: The firewall is not enabled and as for permissions the NDMP credentials are set to the root of the NDMP server.

Comment: NBU 7.0 running on window 2008 directly attached to TL. I am unable to explicitly see the files on the NDMP host for which I am trying to run a backup.